# Plain C reading from a data file

Tags: c, gcc, file-io, scanf

I am using the compiler **gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3** on Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS 32-bit and reading from a file using fscanf function is a bit problematic. The format specifier %f cannot read into variables declared as doubles in the code but %lf works. What is the reason behind this discrepeancy? I am providing a code snippet together with a data file below:

EDIT: I am getting segmentation fault in the larger code where the following code snippet is used. I have tried removing the first two lines and getting rid of char and two fgets calls but it did not work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <fftw3.h>
#define N 3500
int main(void)
{
    FILE * data = fopen("data_1657.dta", "r"), * fft = fopen("fftq3.dat", "w+");
    if(!data) // Checking if the file opened succesfully
        return 1;
    fftw_complex *in, *out;
    fftw_plan forward;
    forward = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    double *t, *ft, *err;
    int i = 0;
    t = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * N);
    ft = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * N);
    err = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * N);
    char str [100];
    fgets(str, 100, data);
    fgets(str, 100, data);
    while (fscanf(data, "%lf    %lf     %lf", &t[i], &ft[i], &err[i]) == 3)
    {
        printf("%lf \t %lf \n", t[i], ft[i]);
        i++;
    }


    fftw_execute(forward);
    fclose(data);
    fclose(fft);
    fftw_destroy_plan(forward);
    fftw_free(in);
    fftw_free(out);
    free(t);
    free(ft);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Corrected loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE * data = fopen("data_1657.dta", "r");
    double t, count, err;
while (fscanf(data, "%lf %lf %lf", &t, &count, &err) == 3)
{
    printf("%f \t %f \t %f \n", t, count, err);
}   


    return 0;
}




  time in seconds       count rate(c/s)  error
   ---------------------    --------      -------
    281.3251281976699829     115.639      21.228
    281.8250962048768997     149.639      22.774
    282.3250641971826553     111.639      21.039
    282.8250322043895721     155.639      23.036
    283.3250001966953278     141.639      22.420
    283.8249682039022446     107.639      20.848
    284.3249361962080002     135.639      22.151
    284.8249042034149170     151.639      22.861
    285.3248721957206726     127.639      21.786
    285.8248402029275894     143.639      22.509
    286.3248081952333450     129.639      21.878
    286.8247760981321335     123.639      21.602
    287.3247441053390503      93.639      20.166
    287.8247120976448059      95.639      20.264
    288.3246801048517227     131.639      21.969
    288.8246480971574783     127.639      21.786
    289.3246161043643951     107.639      20.848
    289.8245840966701508      91.639      20.066
    290.3245521038770676      77.639      19.356
    290.8245200961828232     115.639      21.228
    291.3244881033897400     109.639      20.944
    291.8244560956954956     125.639      21.694
    292.3244241029024124     107.639      20.848
    292.8243920952081680     105.639      20.752
    293.3243599981069565     133.639      22.060
    293.8243280053138733     183.639      24.221
    294.3242959976196289     161.639      23.295
    294.8242640048265457     141.639      22.420
```

By the way without deleting the two header lines in the data file is it possible to begin reading from the third row in the data file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can read a line of text with fgets(). Do that twice for the first two lines, using a buffer which you discard afterwards. Alternatively you can just read chars until you have hit `'\n'` twice.

Comment: I haven't the slightest idea why `%lf` is working for you and `%f` isn't, but you will be happier in the long run if you read entire lines at a time with [`getline`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) (which is not standard, but should exist on this system), and then use [`strtod`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod) to parse the line and convert strings to floating-point quantities. `strtod` plus an inner loop over columns is all you need to parse this input format.  You would skip the first two rows in the outer `getline` loop.

Comment: @Zack I may try that thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Use `fgets()`, `sscanf()` and keep track of line number. and one note: looks like your code drops every even line.

Comment: @Zack why would you prefer strtod over scanf?

Comment: Oh by the way is it not possible to skip lines with fscanf ?

Comment: Yes of course it is but you need to match the format of the first two lines which you are in all reality not interested in.

Comment: It's all to easy to skip lines with `fscanf()`; the only time when newlines aren't skipped is when you use a `%c` or `%[…]` (or `%n`) conversion specification.  All other conversion specifications skip leading white space, including newlines, and hence skip lines when input is required.  Note also that white space in a format string matches an arbitrary sequence of zero or more white space characters, including newlines.  And `fscanf()` calls don't have to skip newlines, or end at a newline.

Comment: @alexander Do you mean my code is not able to save for even lines?

Comment: @PeterSchneider `scanf` has *undefined behavior* on numeric overflow -- the C runtime is allowed to *crash* just because a number in the input file is too large.  `strtod`, by contrast, reports numeric overflow reliably, via `errno`.  You have to write a bunch of glue, but it's doable.  (I usually list several other problems with `scanf` when this comes up, but in this context they are all moot or surmountable by using `fgets`/`getline` plus `sscanf`.)

Comment: Your code save (print) only odd lines (1st, 3rd, 5th ...).

Comment: Your `do { fscanf(…); printf(…); } while (fscanf(…) != 3);` loop is wrong because it reads two sets of numbers for every one printed and because it doesn't check the status of the first `fscanf()`.  You should be leery of `do … while` loops in general; doubly so with I/O.  You need `while (fscanf(…) == 3) { printf(…); }` — a loop tested at the top and explicitly checking every input operation.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have corrected the mistake thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Zack Interesting. The man pages for scanf don't seem to specify overflow behaviour (which could be understood to imply undefined behaviour ;-) ); can you point me to a reference? Not that an overflow seems likely here though.

Comment: @PeterSchneider One more question how can I skip first two lines which are in a different format?

Comment: As I said: start with 2 times fgets().

Comment: @PeterSchneider [N1570](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (closest-to-final-standard public draft of C11) §7.21.6.2 (specification of `fscanf` -- `scanf` and `sscanf` are defined in terms of `fscanf`) last two sentences of paragraph 10 read: "...the
result of the conversion is placed in the object pointed to by the first argument following
the
format
argument that has not already received a conversion result. If this object
does not have an appropriate type, *or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented
in the object*, the behavior is undefined." Emphasis mine.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Nigh-identical wording appears in the same location (that is, the specification of `fscanf`, the section numbers are different) in both C99 and C89.  Note that, as far as I know, there is no wording specifying *how the conversion is done*; for `%...f` it's just "matches an optionally signed floating point number, infinity, or NaN" with syntax the same as for floating-point constants in the language proper (§6.4.4.2).  There's not much in the way of a specification on what happens if *those* are too big, either.

Comment: @PeterSchneider By contrast, the `strtod` family (§7.22.1.3) has specific wording for what happens on overflow (paragraph 10): they return an appropriately signed `HUGE_VAL` and set `errno` to `ERANGE`.

Comment: While you are still at it I am still experiencing problems with the code, namely segmentation fault after implementation into a larger source file. Can you provide some help?

Comment: Vesnog, that's a tad vague ;-). Compile  with all warning on (which will perhaps do some argument checking with scanf) and eliminate all warnings. And use a debugger...

Comment: @PeterSchneider Okay I would try it with the -Wall option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `(f)scanf()` sees `%lf` it expects a pointer to a `double` *(usually 64-bit)*  as opposed to `%f` when it only expects a pointer to a `float` *(usually 32-bit*).

```
scanf: %f — float; %lf — double; %Lf — long double
```

Comment: The size of doubles and floats is implementation dependent and will possibly change even with compiler flags on the same system with the same compiler.

Comment: well but suppose it follows IEE754 - would that make the sizes always fixed?

Comment: @PeterSchneider This is true but irrelevant; `%f` always goes with `float`, `%lf` with `double`, and `%Lf` with `long double`.  (I should have remembered this myself.)

Comment: I just would like to see the sentence "When (f)scanf() sees %lf it expects a pointer to a 64-bit variable" go away because it is plain wrong (as a general statement). It may be true for IEEE floats, I didn't look it up.

Comment: A better way to phrase it all (but I was already making significant changes), would be: _… `%lf`, it expects a pointer to a `double` (usually a pointer to a 64-bit variable), as opposed to `%f` when it only expects a pointer to a `float` (usually a pointer to a 32-bit variable)._  The use of 'usually' covers the normal cases but allows for the eccentric.

Comment: But @Jonathan, the size of the double is completely irrelevant, as you correctly pointed out yourself. It's a distraction.

Comment: Edited to be more exact.

Answer (score 1):

You need `%lf` if you are reading into double variables. scanf is not type safe; you have to help the function by matching format specifiers carefully with variable types. Same thing for `%ld` etc.